# Identify rows with particular value across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Each row has an Id and a Category Presence/Status combo. Sample code:

```
DECLARE @sample_table TABLE (
    Id INT
    ,Category_Alpha BIT
    ,Category_Beta BIT
    ,Category_Charlie BIT
    ,Status_Alpha CHAR(8)
    ,Status_Beta CHAR(8)
    ,Status_Charlie CHAR(8)
    );
INSERT INTO @sample_table
VALUES
    (1,1,0,0,'Approved','Open','Open')
    ,(2,1,1,0,'Pending','Approved','Open')
    ,(3,0,0,1,'Open','Open','Rejected')
    ,(4,0,1,0,'Open','Approved','Open')
    ,(5,1,1,1,'Approved','Rejected','Approved');
SELECT * FROM @sample_table;
```

Produces:

```
Id  Category_Alpha  Category_Beta   Category_Charlie    Status_Alpha    Status_Beta Status_Charlie
1        1               0               0                  Approved    Open        Open    
2        1               1               0                  Pending     Approved    Open    
3        0               0               1                  Open        Open        Rejected
4        0               1               0                  Open        Approved    Open    
5        1               1               1                  Approved    Rejected    Approved
```

So each row can have an "Alpha" (true/false) and a corresponding Status for "Alpha" (Pending, Approved, etc.). The same for the other categories (Beta and Charlie).
Categories that are vacant always have a status of "Open". For example, row with Id=1 has Category_Beta=0 (False), so corresponding Status_Beta is "Open".

I have provided 3 categories in the example (Alpha, Beta, Charlie), but my actual data has over 40 categories.
I want to find rows where ALL non-vacant categories are "Approved". In the provided example, this would be rows 1 and 4.

Comment: So categories with a value of 0 are considered vacant, and not 'existing'? So you only want to check the status of category if the category = 1?

Comment: @Ben - Categories with 0 are indeed vacant, but specifically want to check for corresponding status of "Approved". Vacant categories always have corresponding status "Open", and so have personally been only been looking at xxx_Status='Approved' and ignoring Category_xxx values. Including both here just as closer illustration of actual data and potential for better solutions.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that row 1 and 4 should not be selected? Since they have categories with status of Open?

Comment: @Ben - You are correct. That's a flaw in my description; I'll update the post to better reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would just be a complicated `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where (category_alpha = 0 or status_alpha = 'Approved') and
      (category_beta = 0 or status_beta = 'Approved') and
      (category_charlie = 0 or status_charlie = 'Approved');
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon. This clearly works and is beautiful in its simplicity. My only hesitance is that whereas I gave 3 categories in my example, there are actually 40+ categories and growing (not a good design, but out of my control). Might there be another option beyond designating each in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @JClark . . . You have to specify the column names somewhere and the `where` clause seems as good a place as any.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you like dealing just with the status name:

```
SELECT *
FROM @sample_table
where Status_Alpha in ('Open','Approved') and Status_Beta in ('Open','Approved') and Status_Charlie in ('Open','Approved')
and (Status_Alpha = 'Approved' or Status_Beta = 'Approved' or Status_Charlie = 'Approved');
```